# How can I pass an arithmetic operator based on a condition in JS ? Say + for 'add' and * for 'times'

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JS program, where i have a condition to make some arithmetic operations based on the input.
I need to add two values if i encounter the operation type as 'add' and multiply if i get 'times' as my operator value.

I tried using basic if conditions which can solve my problem , but also gives a lot of boiler plate code. I am trying to minimise the code and optimise it more.

Here is what i tried

```
if (otMethod === 'add') {
    if (method === 'add'){
        // some computation
            result = ( (num + value) + otValue);
        // some more computation 
    }
        else{
        // some computation
        result = ( (num * value) + otValue);
        // some more computation 
    }
} else {
    if (method === 'add'){
        // some computation
            result = ( (num + value) * otValue);
        // some more computation 
    }
        else{
        // some computation
        result = ( (num * value) * otValue);
        // some more computation 
    }
}
```

In this , i had to change the OT calculation based on `otMethod` and had to do arithmetic operation over num based on method `value`.

What my question is , can we dynamically pass the operator itself based on the condition of `method` and `otMethod`, so i can reduce the number of if conditions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you create an object, which contains all the necessary parameters? You can change the value of the operator based on your condition and perform the operations using the values from the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass the operator themselves but you don't need to use operators. You can just use functions instead:

```
function add (a,b) { return a+b }
function times (a,b) { return a*b }

var op = {
    add: add,
    times: times
}

result = op[otMethod](op[method](num, value),otValue);
```

You can make it more readable by formatting it as follows:

```
result = op[otMethod](
             op[method](
                 num,
                 value
             ),
             otValue
         );
```

What this boils down to is you are executing the functions and passing the result to another function. For example, if both `otMethod` and `method` are `add` it becomes:

```
result = add( add(num,value), otValue )
```

Putting the functions in an object allows us to use the square bracket notation to choose which function to execute. The format of the operation above actually has a formal name: it is called the [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

If you can use ES6 then the arrow function syntax makes the code really terse:

```
var op = {
    add: (a,b) => a+b,
    times: (a,b) => a*b
}
```

> **Epilogue - Polish Notation**
>
> Basically the regular notation formula
>
> `(a + b) * c` becomes
>
> `* + a b c` in Polish notation.
>
> The advantage of Polish notation is that it does not require braces to denote operator precedence and also the operator and values are naturally in function call format:
>
> `*( +(a,b), c)`.
>
> The programming language Lisp actually function like this. In Lisp `+` and `*` are not operators but functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (otMethod === 'add') {
      result = eval( "(num " + oprMap[method] + " value) + otValue"  );
    } else {
      result = eval( "(num " + oprMap[method] + " value) + otValue"  );
    }


    var oprMap = {
      "add" : "+",
      "times" : "*"
    }
```

Using eval you can directly put the evaluate operation taking operator from the map.

Comment: Worth to mention this code snippet should be wrapped into scope of curly braces {} i.e. **function** and of course variable defined by **var** changed to **const** for `oprMap` .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this would be to compose the logic of your app from simpler  functional building blocks (ie `doCalculation(operandA, operandB, operator)` as shown below).

Taking an approach like this will greatly simplify the presentation of your code, and in your case, might also makes the code a little easier to extend if needed (ie adding support for other operations, etc).

```js
/* Define a simple, reusable and extendable doCacluation() function like this */
function doCalculation(operandA, operandB, operator) {
  
  switch(operator) {
    case 'add': return operandA + operandB;
    case 'times': return operandA * operandB;
    case 'minus': return operandA - operandB;
    /* etc.. */
  }

}

/* Compose your reusable doCalculation() function to simplify the logic of
   you program */ 
function doCombinedCalculation(method, num, value,otMethod, otValue) {
  
  return doCalculation( doCalculation( num, value, method), otValue, otMethod);
}

console.log( doCombinedCalculation( 'add', 1, 2, 'times', 3 ), ' === ', 9 );
console.log( doCombinedCalculation( 'add', 1, 4, 'minus', 2 ), ' === ', 2 );
console.log( doCombinedCalculation( 'times', 10, 7, 'add', 5 ), ' === ', 75 );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an operator in Javascript as a function parameter per se, you can only try to do an `eval`, however that will open you up to [a whole range of possible security issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

My recommendation is to make use of Javascript's functional programming capabilities and pass another function.

```
// declare the 2 functions 
const add = (x, y) => x + y
const multiply = (x, y) => x * y

// available operations
const ao = { add, multiply }

// otMethod and method can be one of 'add', 'multiply'
console.log(ao[otMethod](ao[method](num, value), otValue))
```

Answer (score -1):

So as per my understanding you need to evaluate same expression based on method name dynamically.
Here's a optimal way to do so

```
    let oMethodMap = {
             'add': '+',
             'times': '*'
    }
    eval(`( (num ${oOperatorMap[otMethod]} value) ${oOperatorMap[otMethod]} otValue)`)
```

Refer [Eval](http://let%20oMethodMap%20=%20%7B%20'add':%20'+',%20'times':%20'*'%20%7D%20%20eval(%60(%20(num%20$%7BoOperatorMap[otMethod]%7D%20value)%20$%7BoOperatorMap[otMethod]%7D%20otValue)%60)) Documentation.